# Error on if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am getting the below error -

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end.

This is driving me nuts! All Im trying to do is:

If there is a URL in the database to their website, hyperlink their name.

If not just echo their name. Simple stuff, what am I missing?

```
  <?php 
  if ($row_clientsP['website']){ 
  ?>
  <a href="<? echo $row_clientsP['website']; ?>"><h2><? echo   $row_clientsP['customerName']; ?></h2></a>
  <? 
  } 
  else
  { 
  ?>
  <h2><? echo $row_clientsP['customerName']; 
  }
  ?></h2>
```

Comment: Using short opening tags could be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have an unclosed `{`.

The could be from elsewhere in the code or from using short tags `<?`, as noted by **Mark Baker**. You can check the value (short_open_tag)[http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag] in your *php.ini*. As a rule though, [I discourage them](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have [short tags `<?`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) enabled these lines will cause that error -

```
<? 
}
```

AND

```
<h2><?
```

It is always best to use `<?php` tags, as most php installations turn off short tags by default.

see also - http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly an issue with the short open tags.  They are "on" on my server and the script parses correctly.  This also parses correctly and uses the full php tags.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_smitty.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($row_clientsP['website']){
?>
<a href="<?php echo $row_clientsP['website']; ?>"><h2><?php echo   $row_clientsP['customerName']; ?></h2></a>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<h2><?php echo $row_clientsP['customerName'];
}
?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use (full php tags)

```
  <?php 
  if ($row_clientsP['website']){ 
  ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $row_clientsP['website']; ?>"><h2><?php echo   $row_clientsP['customerName']; ?></h2></a>
  <?php 
  } 
  else
  { 
  ?>
  <h2><?php echo $row_clientsP['customerName']; 
  }
  ?></h2>
```